# Overriding a game center with new data.

Tags: clash-of-clans, game-center

On my iPhone I have the game clash of clans. I am I pretty high level (83) and I am a th9.... So I am pretty far in this game. Recently, my Game Center started asking me if I wanted to load my th1. I was confused so I looked at my Game Center and for clash of clans it never showed any of the achievements I got and would suggest I am a th1. My clash apparently never saved to my Game Center.  Is there any way to overide my current Game Center with the current data on clash of clans? This would be really helpful because I got a new phone and would like to play coc on it with all my saved things.

Answer (score 2):

The official solution is to email SuperCell support, explaining the situation, to have them erase your existing Game Center account.

In the meantime I suggest you link your account to Facebook so you have backup access to it.